# making a jquery plugin for prettifying html or minifying html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-parsing, nodes

I wanted to make a jquery plugin for prettifying the html code taking the indent spaces as an option.

I wanted to know how to proceed for this. Should I extract each dom element *recursively* & store it & then proceed with it?

**NOTE: I tried the above mentioned procedure, but it doesn't work for than 4-5 tags & the page crashes if there are more dom elements passed in the function.**

The code for the recursive implementation is something like:

```
result="";
function serialize(domNode, indent) {
//get tagname & attributes
result+="<"+tagname+""+attributes+">";
var children=domNode.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
    var node=children[i];
    if(children[i].nodeType==3) {
        result += children[i].data;
    }
    else if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
        result += serialize(children[i], indent);
    }
}
result += "</"+tagname+">";
}
```

**PS: I know the code is bad, so I need some better implementations.**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are you going to display the prettified HTML somehow? If you're wanting the source code to look better, jQuery can't do anything for that, it's too late at that point.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: updated. But I need a way for implementation, dont suggest code improvements

Comment: @dnc253: yup somewhat like that, currently it would be fine if I can store it in a variable say result

Comment: +""+ is redundant and can be replaced with + (or did you mean +" "+ hard to tell since you left out some of the code)